# Why most debuggers don't auto recognize functions?

Tags: debuggers, functions

may anyone explain to me why most of the debuggers don't auto recognize functions?

This is a feature I only found in IDA and ollydbg, any other debugger I tried just don't analyze the functions as IDA and olly do.

I understand that this could be a performance issue to justify don't set this feature as the default behaviour, but why debuggers like x64dbg seems to just don't have the feature?

Thanks.

Comment: The easier answer is "Because debuggers are not aware there is such thinh as a function at all", as they only execute one *instruction* at a time. Even if a list of instructions-to-be-executed is displayed, there is no guarantee *at all* that that is going to happen in that order and with those instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As assembly instruction sets are reasonably complex, properly figuring out a function boundaries inside a big executable binaries is a somewhat difficult task. Even IDA, which specializes in that, has quite a few mistakes and misses in certain scenarios.

This goes back to disassembly strategies, which are basically the algorithm used to provide disassembly listings for given stream of binary. They're often divided to two categories:

1. *Linear Sweep* is to simply disassembly one instruction after the other. The straight-forward way to disassemble a sequence of instructions - start the next instruction disassemble right where the last instruction ended.
2. *Recursive Disassembly* attempts to consider the code flow while disassembling, and will likely hold a stack of "function entries" (every call, for example, will get it's target address in that queue). The queue keeps being emptied by the disassembly engine until all encountered functions are analyzed.

They both have their pros and cons although Linear sweep is considered simpler to implement and recursive disassembly to yield better results.

Most debuggers don't focus too much on the disassembly task because usually, instruction pointer registers will point to the correct function to disassemble and the need to disassemble big binary blobs and recognise functions is rare. Additionally, as mostly static analysis tool IDA puts a lot more focus into exposure of the "whole picture", where debuggers tend to shine a light on only a small piece of the executable at a time.

P.S.

x64dbg is another debugger (considered an ollydbg replacement by some) with decent function discovery.

Comment: Hum I see, so you think the main reason is because function analyze is a complex thing to do? Why do you think olleh did it so well years ago and people can't replicate that nowadays?

Comment: @underthevoid It is indeed a complex algorithm to perfect. I however don't think "people can't replicate" - x64dbg did. As I explained - it is just not a major advantage or focus in a debugger, because most of the time you'll be looking a small pieces of the binary or even only part of a function at a time.

Comment: Hmm the x64dbg have this feature? I couldn't find here. Do you mind telling me where I could find this feature in x64dbg? The "analyze module" is very far from what ollydbg does.

Comment: When I was using x64dbg i found it's analysis capabilities satisfying. If you did not - there isn't anything that could easily improve them. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you :) please let me know if there's anything else I can do to shed more light onto the topic.

Comment: Well, another doubt I had about a similar topic is why do people prefer to debug in a dbg other than IDA. As it seems to me IDA is by far the best disasm/dbg tool we have in the open market, but still there are a lot of ppl using other apps to debug like olly, x64dbg, radare2, etc.

Comment: @underthevoid Preferences such as speed or workflow. For me I was debugging a 50MB binary whose idb was generated of ~600 MB. As soon I started to debug, IDA will rebase the whole binary which would take a lot of time for me.

Comment: @underthevoid IDA's debugger is quite poor. This is even Ilfak's take on it, as it was mostly done "to satisfy demand" and against Ilfak's will. Disassemblers and debuggers are too completely different tools and may be used to slightly different tasks, although there is quite a bit of personal preference to it.

Comment: @NirIzr Umm I see but what makes IDA's debugger quite poor in your opinion? I mean, I see that it can get a bit heavy even for some simple binaries but besides that which functionality is missing in IDA that you can find in x64dbg for instance? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: It's slow, feels clumsy and have an awkward UI, missing a lot of functionality and configuration options other debuggers have. Not to mention the variety of plugins olly has for example compared to IDA's debugging plugins... When I only need little bits or debugging I may use it but when I'm debugging something with anti-debugging IDA is simply not enough.